# Select entry of each group having exactly 1 entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

***I am looking for an optimized query***

let me show you a small example.
Lets suppose I have a table having three field `studentId, teacherId and subject` as

[image]

Now I want those data in which a physics teacher is teaching to only one student, i.e

[image]

teacher **300** is only teaching student **3** and so on.

What I have tried till now

```
select sid,tid from tabletesting with(nolock) 
where tid in (select tid from tabletesting with(nolock)
where subject='physics' group by tid having count(tid) = 1) 
and subject='physics'
```

**The above query is working fine**. But I want different solution in which **I don't have to scan the same table twice**.

I also tried using `Rank()` and `Row_Number()` but no result.

FYI :

I have showed you an example, this is not the actual table i am playing with, my table contain huge number of rows and columns and where clause is also very complex(i.e date comparison etc.), so I don't want to give the same where clause in subquery and outquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with window functions.  Assuming that there are no duplicate students for a given teacher (as in your sample data):

```
select tt.sid, tt.tid 
from (select tt.*, count(*) over (partition by teacher) as scnt
      from TableTesting tt
     ) tt
where scnt = 1;
```

Another way to approach this, which might be more efficient, is to use an `exists` clause:

```
select tt.sid, tt.tid
from TableTesting tt
where not exists (select 1 from TableTesting tt1 where tt1.tid = tt.tid and tt1.sid <> tt.sid)
```

Comment: @learning . . . Please elaborate.  The second query is saying:  select all pairs from the table where the teacher does not have another student.

Comment: You have edited your answer the condition in your where clause was `tt1.sid<>tt.tid`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use an analytic function:

```
select sid, tid, subject from
(
select sid, tid, subject, count(sid) over (partition by subject, tid) cnt
from tabletesting
) X 
where cnt = 1
```